# ray save tensorflow model: OSError: Unable to create file (unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable')

Tags: tensorflow, ray

I use official example to train the mnist dataset, but when I save tf model, it occurred an error, the python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import argparse
import json
import os

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback

import ray.train as train
from ray.train import Trainer


class TrainReportCallback(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        train.report(**logs)


def mnist_dataset(batch_size):
    (x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train / np.float32(255)
    y_train = y_train.astype(np.int64)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).shuffle(60000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return train_dataset


def build_and_compile_cnn_model(config):
    import tensorflow as tf

    learning_rate = config.get("lr", 0.001)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28)),
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        ]
    )
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    return model


def train_func(config):
    per_work_batch_size = config.get("batch_size", 64)
    epochs = config.get("epochs", 3)
    steps_per_epoch = config.get("steps_per_epoch", 70)

    tf_config = json.loads(os.environ["TF_CONFIG"])
    num_works = len(tf_config["cluster"]["worker"])

    strategy = tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()

    global_batch_size = per_work_batch_size * num_works
    multi_worker_dataset = mnist_dataset(global_batch_size)

    with strategy.scope():
        multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_cnn_model(config)

    history = multi_worker_model.fit(
        multi_worker_dataset,
        epochs=epochs,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
        callbacks=[TrainReportCallback()]
    )
    multi_worker_model.save("/multi_worker_model", save_format="h5")
    # tf.saved_model.save(multi_worker_model, "/multi_worker_model")

    result = history.history
    return result


def train_tf_mnist(num_workers=2, use_gpu=False, epochs=5):
    trainer = Trainer(backend="tensorflow", num_workers=num_workers, use_gpu=use_gpu)
    trainer.start()
    result = trainer.run(
        train_func=train_func,
        config={"lr": 1e-3, "batch_size": 64, "epochs": epochs}
    )
    trainer.shutdown()
    print(f"result: {result}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--address", required=False, type=str, help="The address to use for ray")
    parser.add_argument("--num_workers", "-n", type=int, default=4, help="Sets number of workers for training")
    parser.add_argument("--use_gpu", action="store_true", default=False, help="Enable GPU training")
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=3, help="Number of epochs to train for")
    parser.add_argument("--smoke-test", action="store_true", default=False, help="Finish quickly for testing")

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

    import ray
    if args.smoke_test:
        ray.init(num_cpus=2)
        train_tf_mnist()
    else:
        ray.init(address="auto")
        train_tf_mnist(
            num_workers=args.num_workers,
            use_gpu=args.use_gpu,
            epochs=args.epochs
        )
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_test.py", line 117, in <module>
    epochs=args.epochs
  File "train_test.py", line 88, in train_tf_mnist
    config={"lr": 1e-3, "batch_size": 64, "epochs": epochs}
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/trainer.py", line 356, in run
    for intermediate_result in iterator:
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/trainer.py", line 753, in __next__
    self._finish_training
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/trainer.py", line 713, in _run_with_error_handling
    return func()
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/trainer.py", line 824, in _finish_training
    return self._backend_executor.finish_training()
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/utils.py", line 168, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: ray.get(actor_method.remote(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/_private/client_mode_hook.py", line 104, in wrapper
    return getattr(ray, func.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/api.py", line 44, in get
    return self.worker.get(vals, timeout=timeout)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/worker.py", line 438, in get
    res = self._get(to_get, op_timeout)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/util/client/worker.py", line 466, in _get
    raise err
types.RayTaskError(OSError): ray::BackendExecutor.finish_training() (pid=5557, ip=10.0.5.145, repr=<ray.train.backend.BackendExecutor object at 0x7f5ad4cc5490>)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/backend.py", line 498, in finish_training
    results = self.get_with_failure_handling(futures)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/backend.py", line 517, in get_with_failure_handling
    success = check_for_failure(remote_values)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/utils.py", line 50, in check_for_failure
    ray.get(object_ref)
ray.exceptions.RayTaskError(OSError): ray::BaseWorkerMixin._BaseWorkerMixin__execute() (pid=6012, ip=10.0.5.145, repr=<ray.train.worker_group.BaseWorkerMixin object at 0x7f2330318bd0>)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/worker_group.py", line 26, in __execute
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/backend.py", line 489, in end_training
    output = session.finish()
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/session.py", line 118, in finish
    func_output = self.training_thread.join()
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/utils.py", line 96, in join
    raise self.exc
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/utils.py", line 89, in run
    self.ret = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/train/utils.py", line 138, in <lambda>
    return lambda: train_func(config)
  File "train_test.py", line 76, in train_func
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 2112, in save
    signatures, options, save_traces)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 147, in save_model
    model, filepath, overwrite, include_optimizer)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 103, in save_model_to_hdf5
    f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='w')
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 427, in __init__
    swmr=swmr)
  File "/mnt/softwares/hvd_env/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 196, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_TRUNC, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
  File "h5py/h5f.pyx", line 116, in h5py.h5f.create
OSError: Unable to create file (unable to lock file, errno = 11, error message = 'Resource temporarily unavailable')
```

The verion:

```
ray 1.13.0
h5py 3.1.0
tensorflow 2.5.0
```

Comment: Do you have the permissions to write on that folder where you're trying to save?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue without Ray? It seems like the error is being encountered by h5py

Comment: Yes, I have.@claudia

Comment: I can run the code in local mode, but when I use distributed mode, it occurred this error.@cade